# What could cause a browser to not respect set-cookie response headers?

Tags: http, cookies, setcookie

I have a web server which returns `200 OK` with a bunch of set-cookies, and an HTML page which loads a bunch of scripts from the same server.

[image: the response with set-cookie]

However, the subsequent loads that was spawned from that HTML page submits a different cookie on their HTTP request headers.

[image: it gives back a completely different cookie]

What could be causing that? Surely there's some policy I'm missing out on, but I don't see why it works on some pages and not others?

I'm using chrome as the browser, but this behavior also happened from iOS, so I'm guessing it's not browser specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot more reading and troubleshooting, it turns out that when you don't set a cookie path, it'll default to whatever path the original request set-cookie was sent to. And because my resource paths had a different path, the cookie was not sent.

Adding `Path=/` fixed it for my issue. Of course, if you don't want your cookie to be accessible to all pages this is bad, but my web-server requires requests to come with cookies because they are sensitive data (for security reasons).